# Search submits on localsever but does nothing on remote

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a search bar on my website that submits to the next page perfectly fine on my localhost with wamp but when I put it on my hosts server it doesn't submit, it does nothing. If you type in a search term it doesn't even move to the next page it just has the spinny icon in the tab and does nothing and the address bar doesn't change either. It seems to crash but i could be wrong.

```
function OnSubmitForm()
                {
                    if (document.getElementById('Search').value =='')
                    {alert('No search term was entered!')
                return false;
                    }
                    else {
                  if(document.getElementById('Searchby').
                options[document.getElementById('Searchby').selectedIndex].value==0)
                  {
                    document.getElementById('Searchbar').action ="searchdefault.php";
                  }
                  else
                  if(document.getElementById('Searchby').
                options[document.getElementById('Searchby').selectedIndex].value==1)
                  {
                    document.getElementById('Searchbar').action ="MusicSearch.php";
                  }
                  else
                  if(document.getElementById('Searchby').
                options[document.getElementById('Searchby').selectedIndex].value==2)
                  {
                    document.getElementById('Searchbar').action ="DVDSearch.php";
                  }
                  else
                  if(document.getElementById('Searchby').
                options[document.getElementById('Searchby').selectedIndex].value==3)
                  {
                    document.getElementById('Searchbar').action ="BluraySearch.php";
                  }
                    }
                }

<div id="form">
                  <center>
                    <form name="Searchbar" onsubmit="return OnSubmitForm()" id="Searchbar" method="get">

                      Search
                      <input name="Search" type="text" dir="ltr" lang="en" size="50" id="Search" value="" />
                      In
                      <select name="Searchby" size="1" id="Searchby">
                        <option value="0" selected="selected">All Departments</option>
                        <option value="1">Music</option>
                        <option value="2">DVD</option>
                        <option value="3">Bluray</option>

                      </select>
                      &nbsp;
                      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
                    </form>
                  </center>
                </div>
```

Top code is javasrcript directing the browser from what was selected in the drop down menu and text box is where you type the search term. It goes to the search page specified and runs through php and then to a sql statement to display the results on the searchpage.

Heres a link to see the site(NB only use the searchbar.)some of the links are not finished

www.echosrecordbar.co.za

Just a side note, will unsetting the varbles fix the problems?

Please help as I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search seems to work, however it takes very long (umm around 2-5 minutes) before the results start showing. This could mean 2 things -

1. your website might not be hosted on a decent configuration
2. your queries and/or DB structure is not optimized and therefore the search is taking too long to complete - like lack of indexes or expensive joins.

I also noticed that the number of results returned in a search is very large that a browser might take long to load. Try using pagination in your search results.

Comment: It's been hosted on a server with other websites on the server aswell. The db has 69000+ entries in the catelogue table and 6000+ entries of tracklistings. Would it be better for me to get my own server instead of sharing one for the db. I forgot to mention that it did work much better when I only had Half the database up-about 30000 entries.

Comment: It's my query, thats the problem. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer, @Mark. On additional note, the number of entries in your database are not high. It is okay to host on a shared server but I would suggest migrating to a dedicated server when the number of entries grow significantly and depending on the amount of traffic you expect